# Get column in pivot table python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pivot-table

I have a function that contain the params as follow: initial_date and final_date. The return of this function is a dataframe that was pivoted, with months in columns. Example bellow:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ircTs.png)

My problem is: When I pass the params, the number of column change. But i want to get the last column before the "perc_part" column (in picture above). How can I do that?

Comment: Include sample data as code and provide the desired output as code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.